# Orthogonal complement in infinite-dimensional space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, machine-learning

In [A Generalized Representer Theorem](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2001/SchHerSmo01.pdf) page 6, the author wriites:

> ...Given $x_1,...,x_m$, any $f\in\mathcal{F}$ can be decomposed into a part that lives in the
>   span of the φ($x_i$) and a part which is orthogonal to it:  $$f=\sum_{i=1}^m
> \alpha_iφ(x_i) + v $$...

And this is confusing to me. The entire theorem is to show that $f$ is in fact finite dimensional but the proof seems to assume it at the beginning. My question is, given a infinite-dimensional function class $\mathcal{F}$, why can we decompose its element $f$ into finite partial sums? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can $f$, an element of the space (not a space itself) be finite dimensional? Do you maybe want to say that $f$ is a sum of finitely many basis elements, given a particular basis. If that is the case, then this is always true by definition of a vector space and a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from a basic (but none trivial fact) about Hilbert Spaces: Let $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a finite dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{F}$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is closed (since it's finite dimensional). Thus since $\mathcal{F}$ is a Hilbert space (not just any inner product space), we have the decomposition:
$$ \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{S} \oplus \mathcal{S}^{\perp} $$
Where $\mathcal{S}^{\perp} = \{x \vert \; \forall y \in \mathcal{S} \; \langle x,y \rangle = 0 \}$. This Gives the decomposition you mentioned (i.e. decomposing a vector in $\mathcal{F}$ into a finite dimensional part in $\mathcal{S}$ and one in it's orthogonal complement).